# Does the fire rate for Bulwark of Harmony work if you're in an offensive war?

Tags: stellaris

Bulwark of Harmony is a defensive tradition. It's in-game text is below:

[image: Bulwark of Harmony]

It seems clear that ship build speed only takes effect while in a defensive war. However, it's not really clear if the same restriction applies to the fire rate bonus. Is the fire rate bonus only active while in a defensive war or do you need to only be within your own borders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two bonuses are independent:

[image]
You are getting +15% fire rate when you are within your borders. You are getting +33% ship build speed when you are in a defensive war. You are getting both when you are defending while within your borders.

Comment: I actually noticed my fleet power going up and down outside of war as I hoped borders, and there's a line item that shows this bonus if you hover or a single ship. I meant to come back to this to post this info, but hadn't done so yet.