# Does the Bulwark of Harmony tradition work in total war, or against crisis-factions like the Contingency?

Tags: stellaris

[That +33% build-speed bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326882/does-the-fire-rate-for-bulwark-of-harmony-work-if-youre-in-an-offensive-war) is pretty sweet; but what about when the Crisis rolls around? Does the Crisis existing count as a "defensive war", or does that bonus stop being helpful once you're past warring with other local-galactic empires?

Similarly, what about "total war" factions that are at war with you all the time, like Determined Exterminators or whatever? Does that count as a 'defensive war' all the time?

Comment: I could be wrong since it's been a while since I last played, but I believe determined exterminators and other similar empires still need to declare war in order to take/exterminate your systems. This is also true for fallen empires, which is particularly relevant for the hyper aggressive ones. What's not clear to me is how the game treats the factions that are spawned as a crisis and how they attack other empires.